# How to create a slider with a bubble in react native?

Tags: react-native

How to create a slider with a bubble in React Native?

[image: Slider with bubble containing value of slider in bubble]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slider mentioned on screen shot, refers to material design slider.

You are probably looking for [this](https://github.com/vobi-io/react-native-material-slider#readme)

Comment: Thanks @Anus Kaleem. I was looking for this.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Accept this as answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.